# Hi everyone. Is it right not to put any article after this, that?

Tags: articles

Is it right not to put any article after this, that?

Here is an example:

> She found a crooked little sixpence.
>   "What", she said,"shall I do with this little sixpence?"

Why not "...with this ***a*** little sixpence"? Or would the meaning changes because "a" stays before little?

Or does *this* always means *one* so there is no need to put articles?

Answer (score 1):

*This* and *that* (in this context) are determiners, and cannot be followed by another determiner such as an article or possessive.

"This a little sixpence" is not grammatical.